# Are two branches necessarily identical if both rebase and merge are mutually "up-to-date"?

Tags: git, git-merge, rebase, git-merge-conflict

When two branches are reported by **git** as mutually "up-to-date" for *both* **rebase** and **merge**, does this entail that their content must be identical?

Also, I'm thinking the reverse is maybe *not* entailed, since branches with identical content could have unrelated histories that can't be merged? Or, is it instead the case that the mere fact of having identical content automatically supersedes any consideration of history (disjoint or otherwise), meaning identical branches are inherently always allowed to mutually merge/rebase without conflict?

Answer (score 0):

A branch is the name of a single commit. Other commits may be the *parent* of that commit, or the parent of that parent, and so on. Those ancestral commits form the totality commits *reachable* from the branch-named commit.

The way Git compares a branch with another is to see whether either of them leads to reachable commits that the other does *not* lead to. "Up-to-date" (neither ahead nor behind nor both) means that the answer is No. Therefore the branches are identical *for purposes of whatever you are trying to do.*

For instance, let's say you try to merge A into B and Git says "no, it's up to date". That means that all the commits reachable from A are already reachable from B, so there is nothing to do.